# Prior Art - probe to genomic location is a map query

Tags: prior-art-request

In reference to the patent: [US20140256789](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140256789)

Aren't they just performing a query to a location on the map of the genome and describing a feature that exists at a given location?  The patent above covers mapping the genome and doing topological analysis (including any sort of annotation).

Comment: they have used methods and examples for same but claims are directed to isolated micro RNA.

Comment: Please note that the claims are what describe the metes and bounds of patent protection, not the abstract or description/specification. Please also note that the linked document is a publication of a patent APPLICATION, not an actual patent.